# How can i store if checkbox is true using asyncstorage?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm trying to make so, if the checkbox is true it should save it with asyncstorage but no matter what I try, I can't make it to work nor does google get me anything. I'm also new to asyncstorage aswell.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';


export default class Check extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: 'false',

    };
  }

  storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key')
    } catch (e) {

    }
  }

  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
      if(value !== null) {

      }
    } catch(e) {

    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CheckBox
        checkedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-active' size={15} color='#000' />}
        uncheckedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-passive' size={15} color='#000' />}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() => this.setState({ checked: !this.state.checked })}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

UPDATED CODE BELOW

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';


export default class Check extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: false,

    };
  }

  storeData = async () => {
    try {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', JSON.stringnify({checked: false}))
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('error storing data')
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(getData) {
    getData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
        if(value !== null) {
          this.setState({checked: JSON.parse(value).checked})
        }
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('error restoring data')
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CheckBox
        checkedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-active' size={15} color='#000' />}
        uncheckedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-passive' size={15} color='#000' />}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() => this.componentDidMount()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

THIS TEXT IS JUST HERE CUZ OF STACKOVERFLOW COMPLAINING ABOUT MORE CODE THAN TEXT.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I don't see you loading the data from the storage. You should call `getData` function in the componentDidMount lifecycle event and update your state with retreived value.

Also, you should add some item that you want to save. [Here](https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/blob/master/docs/API.md#setItem) is a documentation on how the `setItem` method is used. As you can see, you need to pass some string as well. In your case, that could be something like "checked".

Answer (score 0):

You can only store a string in `AsyncStorage`, So before storing, stringify your object value and also you are `not passing any value while setting the item in AsyncStorage which you wanted to store`, here is the solution.

Store like this.

`await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', JSON.stringnify({checked: false}))`

And get like this

`const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')`

Also after getting value from storage `setState` to that value like this

`this.setState({checked: JSON.parse(value).checked})`

Then called your getData function inside `componentDidMount`

Comment: Could you look at this => https://pastebin.com/bf4PdhNt I don't really get the componentdidmount nor the setstate thingy

Comment: I updated the code above instead, ((the link is working for me))

Comment: Link is working for me now but I didn't get you what you wanted to ask ?

Comment: Could you look at the code and see if i placed the things right. cuz for me it doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 0):

`setItem` take 2 parameters: key & value. Also when you `setState` based on previous state you should call setState with callback. And I see also that you're not calling storeData function any where

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';

import Fontisto from 'react-native-vector-icons/Fontisto';


export default class Check extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: 'false',

    };
  }

  storeData = async () => {
    await this.setState(prevState => ({ checked: !prevState.checked }))
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', this.state.checked)
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  getData = async () => {
    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
      if(value !== null) {
        console.log(value);
      }
    } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CheckBox
        checkedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-active' size={15} color='#000' />}
        uncheckedIcon={<Fontisto name='checkbox-passive' size={15} color='#000' />}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        onPress={() => storeData()}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are calling Async operation on each state change this will cause performance issues.